# How to Enable TLS 1.0 encryption for API integration

Tags: api

Salesforce is going to disable SSL 3.0 encryption on 7th November for all the sandbox instances and later for production instances. In sandbox environment, my .Net client application using OAuth 2.0 Web Server flow and salesforce APIs to communicate with salesforce.  How could I verify that my API integration is using SSL 3.0 encryption and how could I change it to TLS 1.0?